# Fitnesse has page properties removed when checking out from git

Tags: git, fitnesse, git-checkout

After checkout from my git repository every suite and test page have their respective property removed.
Instead there is text at the top of the page:
<s>Test</s>
<s>Suite</s>

This forces me to manually set the property and remove the text for every single page after i checkout a branch.
Am I doing something wrong in how i use version control with Fitnesse or why does this happen?

The current branch can be found here: https://github.com/Suptzs/OnlineLottery/tree/RemoveDuplication

Comment: Not sure why this happens, but those `Test` and `Suite` lines seem to come from ["new style wiki pages"](https://github.com/unclebob/fitnesse/pull/952), supported in recent Fitnesse versions (merged to the master branch in August 2016). Perhaps you are using an older version of Fitnesse?

Comment: I am using the latest release 20161106 from their download page.
Your comment explains why FitNesse's suite consists of content.txt and properties.xml while my newly created files only consist of filename.wiki. I will look into that later today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after legoscia tipped me right direction i came upon this issue in the Fitnesse repository: Wiki page properties not saving properly in version 20161106
https://github.com/unclebob/fitnesse/issues/1013

> Its GIT messing up new wiki pages (.wiki) upon commit.
>
> For now, until this is resolved I'll set all updated projects back to the old-style wiki pages with folders.
>
> It appears a '.gitattributes' file in the FitNesseRoot directory also works, if we explicitly set all .wiki files to have only 'lf' line endings (and not Windows standard 'crlf').
>
> So inside the FitNesseRoot directory we can add a '.gitattributes' file with contents:
>
> `*.wiki text eol=lf`
> This seems to leave the new style wiki pages in working condition.